# How can I alternate the row color in an already created JTable?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable

I know how to alternate row color with this code:

```
JTable table = new JTable(){
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column){
    Component returnComp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    Color alternateColor = Color.YELLOW;
    Color whiteColor = Color.WHITE;
    if (!returnComp.getBackground().equals(getSelectionBackground())){
        Color bg = (row % 2 == 0 ? alternateColor : whiteColor);
        returnComp .setBackground(bg);
        bg = null;
    }
    return returnComp;
};
```

Now I want to change alternate row color in execution time, (e.g. click in a button and change alternate row color from Yellow to Gray).

How I can do it?

Comment: Store the alternate color in a field and have the button's Action change that field.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `JTable` a full class (instead of an anonymous class as you have in your question), then create a method to do the toggling.

```
public class AlternatingJTable extends JTable {
  private static final Color ALTERNATE_ONE = Color.YELLOW;
  private static final Color ALTERNATE_TWO = Color.GRAY;

  private Color alternateColor = ALTERNATE_ONE;
  private Color whiteColor = Color.WHITE;

  @Override
  public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column){
    Component returnComp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

    if (!returnComp.getBackground().equals(getSelectionBackground())){
        Color bg = (row % 2 == 0 ? alternateColor : whiteColor);
        returnComp .setBackground(bg);
        bg = null;
    }
    return returnComp;
  };

  public void toggleAlternateColor() {
    if(this.alternateColor == ALTERNATE_ONE) {
      this.alternateColor = ALTERNATE_TWO;
    } else {
      this.alternateColor = ALTERNATE_ONE;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your `actionListener`, just do

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
  myAlternatingJTable.toggleAlternateColor();
}
```

Comment: @durron597 plus one, but with/by override isSelected and hasFocus will be perfect :-), notice is not required a full class, isn't good idea,